# FindBugs custom detector to check variable naming

Tags: java, variables, findbugs, static-code-analysis

I am working on a custom findbugs plugin which finds the variable naming errors in java classses.

For example **Button** variables must starts with **btn*** and if not, report it.

```
Button btnSave; // It's ok
Button close; //Report it, not starts with btn
```

I have been working on this project for days. I can detect method naming errors, method return value errors etc. *But I can not detect -this simple- variable naming errors.* I tried many code pieces and the findbugs documentation is not helpful on this case.

In addition, I can not debug my custom plugin project and every changes steal my time.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FindBugs is a code analyzer that operates on **bytecode**. Variable names are a property of the **source code**.

You might be better off with a different static analyzer such as PMD that operates on source code.

See also [What are the differences between PMD and FindBugs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4297014/what-are-the-differences-between-pmd-and-findbugs)

Comment: Ooov  :(. Thanks shoover. I am going to  check it.