# a Java code analysis tool for intelliJ and Eclipse is needed

Tags: eclipse, plugins, ide, intellij-idea, code-analysis

Does anyone has an experience with a code analysis tool that has a working plugin for both eclipse and intelliJ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both FindBugs and CheckStyle work well with intelliJ 10 and eclipse. you may have to modify the JVM setting for the plugins to work.

but it works.

Answer (score 0):

have you also tried PMD? http://pmd.sourceforge.net/integrations.html

I'm an intelliJ user but it works for Eclipse. I would prefer FindBugs/PMD to CheckStyle. To be honest I use intelliJ's (9 version) built in Inspection tool as well. You will find this previous thread in SO useful [Checkstyle vs. PMD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184563/checkstyle-vs-pmd)

Found this plugin (multiple integration including PMD/FindBugs) for intelliJ this morning (yet to try) but here's the link http://plugins.intellij.net/plugin/?idea&id=4596